# How can I remove the gaps between these horizontal and centered navigation tabs?

Tags: html, css

My code is available here:
https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B1sXI26Zssw2YUVueDdyUHlrVXM

The problem that I'm facing is that there's some space showing up between my navigation tabs, and I didn't have this problem before I used the 'display: inline' function to center my navigation. What can be done? I've tried using "negative pixel margins" but they don't seem to work at all (They did work in another sample navigation I was experimenting with).

[Here's a screenshot of the output of the code.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CJCoj.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok so I downloaded the files and tested it on my server, what I found was rather strange, but the space was only there when the code was on different lines, I ended up fixing it by putting all the `<li>` elements on one line. You can see the code here: https://gist.github.com/HoogleyB/87de68e1a74480d73150770885e25224

Comment: That's weird. This worked, any idea why it wasn't working earlier though?
And thanks!

Comment: @TariqAziz Glad it worked! Why I will have to find out on my own, please tap that check mark on my answer to mark it as answered. Have a great day!

Answer (score 0):

Try to set margin = 0 . If you are running your code on chrome, it adds additional padding and margin of about 8px on its own. So try to fix that.

Comment: I did try this, even tried negative values which didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried:

`ul li{ margin-left:-6px; }`

Hope it will helps you.

Answer (score 0):

Just so you know, this bug is because you are using display: inline-block;

With inline-block, if your html has breakline between elements you will see a space.
To remove it there is a tricky css thing :

```
ul {
   font-size: 0;
}
li {
   font-size: 12px;
}
```

If you set the parent with a font-size 0 the space will disappear.